# resque-scheduler without rails

Tags: ruby, redis, resque

I am trying run the following code:

```
# Resque tasks
require 'resque/tasks'
require 'resque_scheduler/tasks'
namespace :resque do
 task :setup do
  require 'resque'
  require 'resque_scheduler'
  require 'resque/scheduler'

   # you probably already have this somewhere
   Resque.redis = 'localhost:6379'

   Resque.schedule = {}

   require_relative 'app'
 end
end
```

And app.rb

```
require 'resque'
require 'resque_scheduler'
require 'resque/scheduler'

Resque.enqueue_in(5.days, SendFollowUpEmail, 'id')
```

But I am getting
undefined method `days' for 5:Fixnum

I cannot find an example without rails, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timestamp calculation syntax is provided by one of the [active_support](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html) packages.

If you don't want this dependency, the first parameter of enqueue_in is a number of seconds you can manually calculate. For instance:

```
MINUTES=60
HOURS=60*MINUTES
DAYS=24*HOURS

Resque.enqueue_in(5*DAYS, SendFollowUpEmail, 'id')
```

If you still want to use the fancy timestamp calculation syntax, then you need to install [active_support](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html). You can still do it without having to install Rails:

```
$ gem install active_support
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'active_support/time'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> print 5.days
432000=> nil
```

Example done with ruby 2-0-0.